# what is the LL(1) grammar for it statement?

Tags: parsing

I want to convert LALR(1) grammar to LL(1) grammar especially if statement.

I had used LALR(1) grammar for if statement

```
IF_Stmt -> Matched|Unmatched.
Matched -> if ( Expr_IF ) Matched else Matched | Other.
Unmatched -> if ( Expr_IF ) Matched
             |if ( Expr_IF ) Matched else Unmatched.
```

Here, I had realized that i have to remove Left factoring.

After that i couldn't solve epsilon production problem...

What is the LL(1) grammar for if-statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF_Stmt -> if ( Expr_IF ) Stmt Optional_Else_Stmt
Optional_Else_Stmt -> (empty-string)
                      |else Stmt.
```

Comment: Could you describe what you're doing differently than the OP and why your solution works. This helps when someone comes looking at this post in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much your recommendation. 
BTW If i added your grammar to my whole grammar, there was epsilon production problem..

Program -> Stmt Pro.

Pro -> Stmt Pro.

Stmt ->Declare|Assign|IF_Stmt|Compound_Stmt|Iter_FOR|Function_Call
        |Function_body|Comment_line.

Other -> Declare|Assign|Compound_Stmt|Iter_FOR|Function_Call
         |Function_body|Comment_line.

Comment: The above grammar is not LL(1). The symbol "else" conflicts because it is both in FIRST(Optional_Else_Stmt), and in FOLLOW(Optional_Else_Stmt) (assuming IF_Stmt is a Stmt). So "else" would be in the PREDICT set of both branches of Optional_Else_Stmt.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stmt -> if ( Expr ) Matched Optional_Else_Tail
      | Other

Matched -> if ( Expr ) Matched else Matched
         | Other

Optional_Else_Tail -> else Stmt
                    | ""
```